# 2 MySQL installations (now one lost)

Tags: mysql, macos

Ok I have a mess of a problem. MySQL was installed on my machine (mac) already but I could not login via terminal (fairly new machine, to me). I had already been working with a couple databases via a SequelPro and decided to login via terminal for a couple jobs.

I couldn't and couldn't figure out why not. I ran brew install mysql and to my surprise it installed mysql. When logging in via terminal I was taken to this instance of MySQL that did not have my databases. Now, I restart SequelPro and it now logs into the new instance vs the one that has my data.

Any idea where I can find my databases and get them to use this new instance? Or any thoughts on how to clean things up in general?

---update---

The DB is InnoDB

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/bin/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/include/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/include/mysql/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/share/doc/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/share/mysql
/usr/local/include/mysql
/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/mysql
/usr/local/opt/mysql
/usr/local/share/doc/mysql
/usr/local/share/mysql
/usr/local/var/mysql
/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql
```

/usr/local/var/mysql is where my databases from the first instance are. /Cellar is where homebrew installed MySQL. I got a recommendation in the comments to add a symlink...not sure which folder I should use as source or target in this case.

Also, not sure how I would start the database from the old location either.

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: your my.cnf files seems to be overwritten, thus loosing your database location. The old database might (or actually should) still be there. To find it: Open a command prompt as root user, go to /, search the disk for all occurrences of mysql: ls -alR|grep mysql (or similar). This should get you all locations of where your database might reside.

Comment: Thanks. I found the databases. Any idea on the best way to import them into the new instance?

Comment: If it was an ISAM database, you can get away with a create database and then copying the files over into the directory created by mysql. If it was InnoDB, you will really start the database with the old location, or use a symlink: Move the new location to a new directory (rename the directory), and create a symlink **ln -s source target**

Comment: I added an update to make sure everything is clear and we can close this question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Short script to get the old db running:

```
GO to the working database data location
Go up one directory
Shutdown any mysqld.
mv database_directory database_directory.backup
Symlink the data directory of any other mysql:
ln -s old_data_directory database_directory
```

Comment: Ok, the goal is now to identify: **database_directory**: Which of your list contains a database/databases. And **old_data_directory**: What is the path to your old database. Once you substitute those values, start mysql, you can export your database and after one more time replacing the symlink, import it in the new one (or just keep running with the old one).